# GASソートがうまくいかない: TypeError: オブジェクト 1680 で関数 getRange が見つかりません。

Tags: google-apps-script

以下でソートしようとするとエラーが出る。なぜ。

```
TypeError: オブジェクト 1680 で関数 getRange が見つかりません。
  （行 5、ファイル「元2」）表示しない
```

```
function A() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var origin = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('元2');
  var origin_last_row = origin.getLastRow();
  origin_last_row.getRange(2, 1, origin_last_row-1).sort([1,2,12]);
}
```

Comment: `origin.getLastRow()` の戻り値は Integer 型(最終行の行番号)ですので、`getRange()` メソッドがありません。

Comment: なるほど、できました。有難うございます。

Answer (score 0):

`origin.getLastRow()` の戻り値は Integer 型(最終行の行番号)ですので、`getRange()` メソッドがありません。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61828/gas%e3%82%bd%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e3%81%8c%e3%81%86%e3%81%be%e3%81%8f%e3%81%84%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment67371_61828) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*